# jasmine server started command ((bundle exec rake jasmine:ci --trace)) took more than 10 minutes since last output

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jasmine, circleci

I am having a problem with jasmine CI on circleci for continues integration test. Whenever I run jasmine the following command on my local dev machine I got everything okey using the `bundle exec rake RAILS_ENV=test jasmine:ci`.

```
Puma 2.12.2 starting...
* Min threads: 0, max threads: 16
* Environment: development
* Listening on tcp://0.0.0.0:55786
jasmine server started
..........
10 specs, 0 failures
```

But when the same command goes on circleci server, it was getting timeout error.

```
export RAILS_ENV="test"
export RACK_ENV="test"
bundle exec rake jasmine:ci --trace
** Invoke jasmine:ci (first_time)
** Invoke jasmine:require_json (first_time)
** Execute jasmine:require_json
** Invoke jasmine:require (first_time)
** Invoke environment (first_time)
** Execute environment
** Execute jasmine:require
** Invoke jasmine:configure (first_time)
** Execute jasmine:configure
** Invoke jasmine:configure_plugins (first_time)
** Execute jasmine:configure_plugins
** Execute jasmine:ci
Puma 2.12.2 starting...
* Min threads: 0, max threads: 16
* Environment: test
* Listening on tcp://0.0.0.0:43088
Waiting for jasmine server on 43088...

jasmine server started command ((bundle exec rake jasmine:ci --trace)) took more than 10 minutes since last output
```

If anyone have similar problem resolved please let me know. In case if I miss to add any specific configuration or log whatever it is, please also let me know about them.
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

yeah, I have the same problem with last version of `puma` (3.2.0).

Update of `jasmine.yml` helped for me:

```
rack_options:
  server: 'webrick'
```